# ScalikeJDBC: Connection pool is not yet initialized.(name:'default)

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, scalikejdbc

I'm playing with `ScalikeJdbc` library. I want to retrieve the data from PostgreSQL database. The error I get is quite strange for me. Even if I configure manually the CP:

```
val poolSettings = new ConnectionPoolSettings(initialSize = 100, maxSize = 100)
ConnectionPool.singleton("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test", "user", "pass", poolSettings)
```

I still see the error. Here is my DAO:

```
class CustomerDAO {

  case class Customer(id: Long, firstname: String, lastname: String)
  object Customer extends SQLSyntaxSupport[Customer]

  val c = Customer.syntax("c")

  def findById(id: Long)(implicit session: DBSession = Customer.autoSession) =
    withSQL {
      select.from(Customer as c)
    }.map(
      rs => Customer(
        rs.int("id"),
        rs.string("firstname"),
        rs.string("lastname")
      )
    ).single.apply()

}
```

The App:

```
object JdbcTest extends App {
  val dao = new CustomerDAO
  val res: Option[dao.Customer] = dao.findById(2)
}
```

My `application.conf` file

```
# PostgreSQL
db.default.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
db.default.user = "user"
db.default.password = "pass"

# Connection Pool settings
db.default.poolInitialSize = 5
db.default.poolMaxSize = 7
db.default.poolConnectionTimeoutMillis = 1000
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool is not yet initialized.(name:'default)
    at scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ConnectionPool.scala:57)
    at scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ConnectionPool.scala:55)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool$.get(ConnectionPool.scala:55)
    at scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool$.apply(ConnectionPool.scala:46)
    at scalikejdbc.NamedDB.connectionPool(NamedDB.scala:20)
    at scalikejdbc.NamedDB.db$lzycompute(NamedDB.scala:32)
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To load `application.conf`, scalikejdbc-config's `DBs.setupAll()` should be called in advance.

http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/configuration.html#scalikejdbc-config

https://github.com/scalikejdbc/hello-scalikejdbc/blob/9d21ec7ddacc76977a7d41aa33c800d89fedc7b6/test/settings/DBSettings.scala#L3-L22

Comment: @Finkelson Can you post details how you resolved this issue?

Comment: Recently, I ran into this problem. I have always read the db-settings from (`typesafe`) `config` files manually and then created a `ConnectionPool` using those settings, so the `DBs.setupAll()` solution wasn't relevant for me. I tried waiting for the initialization using `while(!ConnectionPool.isInitialized(name)) {}` but that also didn't work. My fix was rather strange: changing `ConnectionPool.add(name="", ...)` to `ConnectionPool.singleton(...)` got rid of the error. I wonder how moving from *custom-named* `ConnectionPool` to *default -named* `ConnectionPool` could alter the behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I omit `play.modules.enabled += "scalikejdbc.PlayModule"` in `conf/application.conf` using [ScalikeJDBC Play support](https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc-play-support)...

Comment: Any concrete reason why that works?