# Play framework 2.5: ScalikeJDBC: Connection pool is not yet initialized on start

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, scalikejdbc

After upgrading to 2.5 version of Play I'm facing this problem when I try to run project in production mode. It seems like in this version I need to initialize pool manually [ScalikeJDBC: Connection pool is not yet initialized.(name:'default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123011/scalikejdbc-connection-pool-is-not-yet-initialized-namedefault)
I can't understand how can I do this.
I've added this class:

```
import play.api.Logger
import scalikejdbc._
import scalikejdbc.config._

class DbInitializer {
    DBs.setupAll()
    Logger.debug("DB initialized")
}
```

and in my module mark it as EagerSingleton:

```
class GlobalModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[DbInitializer]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Now when I run my project in production I see:

> [info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default' [info]
>   p.a.d.DefaultDBApi - Database [default] connected at
>   jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/inetshop [debug] application -
>   [debug] application - DB initialized
>   Oops, cannot start the server. com.google.inject.CreationException:
>   Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Connection pool is not yet initialized.(name:'default)   at
>   controllers.Application.(Application.scala:20)

So my Initializer run successfully but still facing this problem. Need help to fix this.

Comment: What `DBs.setupAll()` does?

Comment: Here http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/configuration.html#scalikejdbc-config they said: "After just calling scalikejdbc.config.DBs.setupAll(), Connection pools are prepared."

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, (Connection pools settings were ignored) not exactly the same, but maybe it helps:

we had to enable the scalikejdbc-play-dbapi-adapter:
build.sbt:
"org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-play-dbapi-adapter" %

and add to application.conf:
play.modules.enabled += "scalikejdbc.PlayDBApiAdapterModule"